# Import error for large negative numbers from CSV to Access using TransferText

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm importing data from a CSV file into an Access table.  The number is something like
-21000000 (-2.1E7).  I'm using TransferText to do the import.

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "matching report temp", Source_folder & "\" & Source
```

In the "matching report temp" table, the field is set up as Double.  The import generates a type conversion failure.  However, when I open the CSV file in Excel and copy the offending row, I can successfully use Paste Append to add it to the table manually - so the number doesn't exceed the capacity of the field.

As far as I can tell, this only happens with large negative numbers.  Smaller numbers, and positive numbers of the same magnitude seem to import fine.  I know I can specify an Import Specification in TransferText, but I don't see a way to set the field type to Double.

How can I get around this problem?  I don't want to have to manually track down the import errors and append them by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't let `TransferText` create the Access table for you.  Create the Access destination table first and assign the field types you need.

When you run `TransferText`, the CSV data will be appended to that existing table.  It should work without error as long as you choose compatible data types for the Access fields.

I examined your CSV file.  The header row is troublesome because some field names are missing:

```
Reporting Unit,,$ Dollars,Offset Unit,,$ Dollars,Variance
```

That seemed to be a complication for `DoCmd.TransferText`.  So I imported manually from the Access UI.  And that gave me an import error on row 49 with the 3rd and 6th columns.  In Access, the destination fields were both created as Long Integer.  However the values for those fields in the CSV row are 2262169190 and -2262169190 ... both beyond the capacity of Access' Long Integer,  -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

As a cheap workaround, I selected Text for the data type of those 2 columns when I imported.  That allowed the import to work without error.  Once you get the data into Access successfully, you could cast those (string) values to a numeric type when you need to use them.

It also worked when I chose Double as the type for those 2 columns.   It sounds like that's what you actually want.

If you want to get the import working with `DoCmd.TransferText`, I think you'll need to create an import specification.  If possible, I would also first modify the header line of the CSV file so that all the fields have names.

I actually tested that approach without altering the CSV file.  After creating an import specification in the Access UI (see screen capture below), this `TransferText` operation worked in Access 2007 without import errors.

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, _
    "IC_Y1301_Specification", _
    "IC_Y1301_LD10279_F25210001", _
    "C:\Users\hans\Downloads\IC_Y1301_LD10279_F25210001.CSV", _
    True
```

[image: TransferText Import Specification]

Comment: That's what I am doing - "Matching report temp" is an existing table with the appropriate field definitions - in this case, Number format and Double field size.  TransferText is appending records to this table - and I'm still getting the type conversion failure.

Comment: I tried it with Long instead of Double in the destination table and got the same i9mport errors.

Comment: OK - I tried.  1st, I think I had the wrong record before - it looks like the offending value is -2.3E9, not -2.1E7.  2nd, I cannot isolate the offending record in a single line - when I edit the file in either Excel or Notepad (to keep it as text), the bad record imports fine.  When I load the entire file, I still get the error.  It's isolated to an input file of about 55 records - where is a good place to upload it for you to look at?  And BTW - thanks for taking so much time on it for me.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sh654ym9nxq1hwc/IC_Y1301_LD10279_F25210001.CSV    --  row 50 is the record that gives me the conversion error

Comment: Added a field name on row 1 and changed the destination field to TEXT - no luck.  I think I'm going to put a step in to open it as an excel workbook then import it.  I cannot find a way around whatever LongInteger conversion is going in inside of TransferText.  Thanks for working on it for me.

Comment: Now I see what to do - I tried to create an import spec with the "append" setting instead of "new table" - and didn't get the options you show above.  Now that I cna see where to create the import spec, I'm all set.  Thank you again for all yout time today.